# Office Addin - No support for IE11

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-store

Is there a way to explicitly mention that the Add-in will not be supported in IE11 through the `manifest.xml`. As there are few features that require IE Edge, the add-in is getting rejected for issues in IE11.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot explicitly declare support for specific versions of Office or Browsers.

More importantly, even if you were able to, failing to support IE11 would result in your Add-in not supporting Office for Windows as both 2013 and 2016 use an embedded IE11 instance to host add-ins.

If you have code that requires support for specific JavaScript or HTML functionality, you either need to provide an alternative for browsers that lack that support or use a polyfill to support that functionality.

I'd highly recommend taking a look at [Polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/).